# use function in sapply R

Tags: r

I need to create an histogram with the function in #2, someone have an idea? i get the warning message :
In hist(as.integer(project.timeV)) : NAs introduced by coercion

```r
#1.
roundNorm <- function(m, sd) { #m is Mean, sd is Standard Deviation
  x <- rnorm(1,m,sd)
  roundUp.X <- ceiling(x)
  return(roundUp.X)
}

#2.
project <- function(x) { # route 1: A-B-C-F, route 2: A-D-E-F
  a.time <- roundNorm(10,3)
  b.time <- roundNorm(10,3)
  c.time <- 5
  d.time <- 10
  e.time <- roundNorm(5,2)
  f.time <- 4
  if(b.time+c.time > d.time+e.time){
    projectLength <- a.time+b.time+c.time+f.time
    criRoute <- "A,B,C,F"
    answer <- c(projectLength,criRoute)
  }
  else {
    projectLength <- a.time+d.time+e.time+f.time
    criRoute <- "A,D,E,F"
    answer <- c(projectLength,criRoute)
  }
  return(answer)
}

#3.
samp <- 1:10000
project.timeV <- sapply(samp,project)
hist(as.integer(project.timeV))
```

Comment: what is `project.timeV`? is it a string? compare `as.integer('a')`

Comment: @MichaelChirico ```project.timeV``` supposed to be vector that I will use to make the histogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do this, I get no errors.

```
project.timeV <- sapply(samp, project, simplify = FALSE)
project.timeV <- do.call(rbind, project.timeV)
hist(as.integer(project.timeV[, 1]))
```

Here is a preview of what the result looks like. Notice that I do not want `sapply` to simplify my result. This is something I do with `do.call` because I want to flatten by rows, not columns.

```
> head(project.timeV)
     [,1] [,2]     
[1,] "34" "A,D,E,F"
[2,] "34" "A,B,C,F"
[3,] "26" "A,D,E,F"
[4,] "24" "A,B,C,F"
[5,] "29" "A,D,E,F"
[6,] "30" "A,D,E,F"
```

Comment: that works, but I don't understand what you did with ```do.call```

Comment: @YshaiSiboni if you examine the result after `sapply` you will notice that it's a list and each element holds a vector or a matrix of 1 row. `do.call` works on lists and applies `rbind` function to all elements. It effectively flattens the list row-wise.